# Scrapy xpath returning 0 instead of the actual price

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

The site I'm trying to scrape is https://coins.ph. Whenever I try to extract from scrapy shell it returned 0 instead of the actual price which I can see in the Chrome Dev console.

Here's the code I'm running:

```
>>> response.xpath('//*[@id="bitcoin-buy-price"]').extract()
['<span id="bitcoin-buy-price">0</span>']
>>>
```

And here's what it looks like in the Chrome Dev Console

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if they are detecting you as a scraper and feeding you false data.

Comment: data is being loaded via AJAX calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an AJAX request being made when you connect to the page.
If you check "Network" tab in your "Web Inspector" (ctrl+shift+i in chromium for example) you can see:

[image]

So a GET request is being made to this address to retrieve the pricing:

https://quote.coins.ph/v1/markets/BTC-PHP

All you need to do is connect to that address and you can load the response with `json.loads(response.body)` function and parse it as a dict.